# "Bundle install" keeps asking me to install individual gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, installation, bundle

I’m running Ruby v 2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 Linux …

```
myusername@mymachine:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

Lately it seems that whenever I run “bundle install” from a remote script, I’m always asked to install the gems individually.  This doesn’t happen when I develop locally on my Mac Sierra.  Note the error message below

```
localhost:runtrax davea$ sh /opt/scripts/pushrt "Corrected processing with regards to RockNRoll site."
[master 0def218] Corrected processing with regards to RockNRoll site.
 11 files changed, 108 insertions(+), 46 deletions(-)
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 3.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@gitlab.com:myusername/myproject.git
   891a010..0def218  master -> master
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 3.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production...
remote: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.5) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.13.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by   running `gem install bundler`.
remote: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote: Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote: Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote: Using rake 11.3.0
remote: Using Ascii85 1.0.2
remote: Using i18n 0.7.0
remote: Using json 1.8.3
remote: Using minitest 5.9.1
remote: Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote: Using builder 3.2.2
remote: Using erubis 2.7.0
remote: Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote: Using rack 1.6.4
remote: Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote: Using arel 6.0.3
remote: Using addressable 2.4.0
remote: Using afm 0.2.2
remote: Using execjs 2.7.0
remote: Using sass 3.4.22
remote: Using byebug 9.0.6
remote: Using chronic 0.10.2
remote: Using chunky_png 1.3.7
remote: Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote: Using thor 0.19.1
remote: Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote: Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
remote: Using ffi 1.9.14
remote: Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote: Using tilt 2.0.5
remote: Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
remote: Using unf_ext 0.0.7.2
remote: Using multipart-post 2.0.0
remote: Using hashery 2.1.2
remote: Using hashie 3.4.6
remote: Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote: Using jwt 1.5.6
remote: Using kgio 2.10.0
remote: Using net-http-digest_auth 1.4
remote: Using net-http-persistent 2.9.4
remote: Using ntlm-http 0.1.1
remote: Using webrobots 0.1.2
remote: Using multi_xml 0.5.5
remote: Using net-telnet 0.1.1
remote: Using oauth 0.5.1
remote: Using ruby-rc4 0.1.5
remote: Using ttfunk 1.4.0
remote: Using pg 0.19.0
remote: Using puma 3.6.0
remote: Using bundler 1.13.5
remote: Using raindrops 0.17.0
remote: Using rubyzip 1.2.0
remote: Using ruby-ole 1.2.12
remote: Using socksify 1.7.0
remote: Using tor 0.1.2
remote: Using will_paginate 3.1.5
remote: Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote: Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1
remote: Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote: Using mime-types 3.1
remote: Using autoprefixer-rails 6.5.1
remote: Using uglifier 3.0.2
remote: Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
remote: Using whenever 0.9.7
remote: Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote: Using compass-core 1.0.3
remote: Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
remote: Using sprockets 3.7.0
remote: Using unf 0.1.4
remote: Using faraday 0.9.2
remote: Using omniauth 1.3.1
remote: Using turbolinks 5.0.1
remote: Using pdf-reader 1.4.0
remote: Using postgresql 1.0.0
remote: Using unicorn 5.1.0
remote: Using spreadsheet 1.1.4
remote: Using tor_requests 0.6.0
remote: Using activesupport 4.2.7.1
remote: Using loofah 2.0.3
remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
remote: Using w3c_validators 1.2
remote: Using mail 2.6.4
remote: Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote: Using compass 1.0.3
remote: Using listen 3.0.8
remote: Using domain_name 0.5.20160826
remote: Using oauth2 1.2.0
remote: Using omniauth-oauth 1.1.0
remote: Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote: Using globalid 0.3.7
remote: Using activemodel 4.2.7.1
remote: Using jbuilder 2.6.0
remote: Using pundit 1.1.0
remote: Using spring 2.0.0
remote: Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote: Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/cache/roo-2.5.1.gem. It may be corrupted.
remote: An error occurred while installing roo (2.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote: Make sure that `gem install roo -v '2.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: Bundler::GemNotFound: Your bundle is locked to roo (2.5.1), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed    sources, that means the author of roo (2.5.1) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of roo (2.5.1) that hasn't been removed in order to  install.
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
remote: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find roo-2.5.1 in any of the sources
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!  
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `specs'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /home/rails/myproject/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
remote: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What else do I need to configure so that “bundle install” just works, as it does on my local machine?

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile and /opt/scripts/pushrt? I suspect there may be an issue with the groups defined in your Gemfile or the options being passed to bundler.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning it is telling you that the gemfile was created by an older version of bundler. Try updating bundler as it suggests:

```
gem install bundler
```

You are also having an issue with the roo gem. It says that it might be corrupted. Try and install it again:

```
gem install roo -v '2.5.1'
```

Then run bundle install again.

Comment: I tried upgrading the bundler using "gem install bundler" but that didn't fix things.  I realize I can run the command, "gem install roo -v '2.5.1'" but every time I add a new gem (roo is just an eexample), I'm asked to install it individually.  I'm not asked to do this on my Mac.  Why is that?

Comment: might be a permission issue. Another error you get is this line: "remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". Apparently it means that you need to input a password to install but bundler doesn't input passwords so it just jumps. Try in your remote command line "sudo visudo" and change its content to "username ALL = NOPASSWD:". This should stop it from asking for a password and bundler should be able to run through.

Comment: The visudo command opens the config file for sudoers and lets you change the permissions and password. Usually it is set to ask always for password but since bundler is having issues, you can turn it off.